# Script to watch a folder for changes, and if modified copy all items inside to another folder

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal

Is there a way to make a bash script that watches a folder for changes, and if it is ever modified, copy the contents of it to another folder?

Comment: Yes, use `cron jobs` and define intervals

Comment: Thx, I will try that!

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no really "clean" way to do this ; from what I know, either you have to get a watcher in background running constantly, or make an interval-based watcher (I have no idea if there's an OOP-like observer in scripting).

So if you want to try the first suggestion, then you have to make a script that runs constantly with an infinite loop, which checks your folder's last edit time and stores it. If any change is applied to it, then your script would notice the difference between the last stored time and the new one.

If you want to do the same thing but without an infinite loop, then you can use Crontab to assign an interval-based checking. The code would be the same as the previous one, but you'll surely have to store the time in a text file.

Then you only have to add some more code to copy the contents of the watched folder to another directory of your choice.

I hope this could help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish not to use any tool, you can write your own script and run in background to monitor. The following way try to calculate md5hash if any content changes in any file. you control by increase sleep interval

**monitor.sh**

```
while true
do
    mdhash1=`find /path/to/folder -type f -exec md5sum {} \; | sort -k 2 | md5sum`
    sleep $1 
    mdhash2=`find /path/to/folder -type f -exec md5sum {} \; | sort -k 2 | md5sum`

    if [ "$mdhash1" = "$mdhash2" ]; then
       echo "Identical"
    else
       echo "Different"
       cp -vr /path/to/folder /path/to/destination/
    fi
done
```

> Note: This will cause performance issue

**Execution**

```
./monitor.sh 2 &
```